# iOS Bluetooth Low Energy connection with external device

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I made a simple device made by a friend with some sensors and a bluetooth module. Right now the module is 3.0 so I know it's next to impossible to connect with my iPhone to it.

My questions is what specs and settings are required for a Bluetooth Low Energy module to connect with an iPhone so that I can receive data from it ?

Comment: bluetooth is bluetooth, really... if the device confirms to the bluetooth specs and does the communications properly, you should be able to use anything...

Comment: Recommending things is off topic for Stack Overflow, so I won't add this as an answer, but have a look at the LightBlue Bean; It has an in-built Arduino and an iOS framework available. The only thing to be a bit careful of is that it is 3.3v so you may need a level convertor if you want to do 5V things with it.

Comment: @MarcB; Not on iOS.  Only BLE/BT 4.0 devices can be connected without the device being Apple certified under their MFi program

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you need to connect to the device
2. Next, once connected, you need to start looking for the device services
3. After that, when you discover your main service, or the service you want, you have to look for its Characteristics
4. Finally, once you discover the wanted characteristic, you need to subscribe to it by using the

> `[myPeripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:aChar];`

Actually, It too long to explain all the detail, take a look at the official documentation, and its really something.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothOverview/CoreBluetoothOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH2-SW1

good luck ;)